# freediameter - No remaining suitable candidate to route the message

Tags: free-diameter

Well, I've started a simple project with freediameter library. what I need to achieve in my project is to create a client diameter application that could send some CCR request to a diameter server.

for this matter, I tried to create a new extension for freediameter daemon.
So, the first thing I did was to setup the peer diameter server in config file:

`ConnectPeer = "vm-pc.my.domain" { No_TLS; ConnectTo = "192.168.56.2"; Port=3868; };`

and then initialize a request message in `ta_entry` function, in message body i specified the Destination-Host and Destination-Realm but still I receive this error:

`01/10/17,01:55:24.980611  ERROR  Routing error: 'No remaining suitable candidate to route the message to' for the following message:
01/10/17,01:55:24.980620  ERROR     'Credit-Control-Request'
01/10/17,01:55:24.980628  ERROR       Version: 0x01
01/10/17,01:55:24.980635  ERROR       Length: 20
01/10/17,01:55:24.980642  ERROR       Flags: 0xC0 (RP--)
01/10/17,01:55:24.980649  ERROR       Command Code: 272
01/10/17,01:55:24.980656  ERROR       ApplicationId: 4
01/10/17,01:55:24.980664  ERROR       Hop-by-Hop Identifier: 0x00000000
01/10/17,01:55:24.980671  ERROR       End-to-End Identifier: 0xDCA05EF4
01/10/17,01:55:24.980678  ERROR        {internal data}: src:(nil)(0) rwb:0x0 rt:0 cb:0x80523df30,0x0(0x803397da0) qry:0x0 asso:0 sess:0x0
01/10/17,01:55:24.981562  ERROR        AVP: 'Session-Id'(263) l=8 f=-M val="hadi-pc.my.domain;1484000714;6"
01/10/17,01:55:24.981569  ERROR        AVP: 'Origin-Host'(264) l=8 f=-M val="hadi-pc.my.domain"
01/10/17,01:55:24.981577  ERROR        AVP: 'Origin-Realm'(296) l=8 f=-M val="my.domain"
01/10/17,01:55:24.981584  ERROR        AVP: 'Destination-Host'(293) l=8 f=-M val="vm-pc.my.domain"
01/10/17,01:55:24.981591  ERROR        AVP: 'Destination-Realm'(283) l=8 f=-M val="my.domain"
01/10/17,01:55:24.981599  ERROR        AVP: 'Auth-Application-Id'(258) l=12 f=-M val=4 (0x4)
01/10/17,01:55:24.981606  ERROR        AVP: 'CC-Request-Type'(416) l=12 f=-M val='EVENT_REQUEST' (4 (0x4))
01/10/17,01:55:24.981613  ERROR        AVP: 'CC-Request-Number'(415) l=12 f=-M val=2 (0x2)`

Can anybody help me on this ?
ps: as I see in the logs the CER/CEA are normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Origin-Realm was signaled in the Capability-Exchange-Answer message when the connection was established?

The Diameter request routing process (as described in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6733#section-6.1) relies on the realm, so if the Origin-Realm returned by the peer is not "my.domain", freeDiameter will not route to this peer, even if the Origin-Host matches.

Comment: Thank you Matt ^_^